# Integrate IP Restricted API on PHP

Tags: php, json, api

I am integrating an IP-Restricted API from a company called XendPay. They allowed requests from the Server IP only. I know PHP scripts run on server but I am not getting response when I request data.
Here is an example:

```
$jsonRequestURL = 'http://uat.xendpay.com/partner/api/1.0/{partner_key}/quote?countryFrom=PL&countryTo=GB&currencyFrom=PLN&currencyTo=GBP&deliveryType=BANK_TRANSFER&paymentMethod=banktransferlocal&amount=1000.00&amountCurrency=PLN&indent=true';
json_decode ( file_get_contents ( $jsonRequestURL ) );
```

It sometimes stuck here or after waiting quite long, gives the following error:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond.

I am not sure but I assume that request is not being sent through Server IP as I have called above mentioned json_decode() on pageload.

Can anyone suggest what should I do?

Comment: Check that you have put the right ip in the app settings, and also check that the request url is correct.

Comment: So the problem will be with API Configuration and I am integrating it correctly if URL is right?

Comment: Yes, your code seems to be correct. I assume that you have just excluded {partner_key}, and you aren't actually including curly braces in the url

Comment: Of course, I did it intentionally. 
I will ask provider to check IP White-list again. Thank you so much for your assistant.

Comment: Double check that you have the right IP for the server, done that once or twice myself.